# Linq query to select all numbers that match

Tags: c#, linq

I have some difficulties to query a table. In the table there are a column for `ResourceID` and a column for `ProjectID`. I want to get a list of all `int` numbers from the `ResourceID` where `ProjectID` match the `projId` number. Is this possible?

I have tested, but I guess this is wrong. I thought I could get the value by using the `resources` variable, but that isn't working.

```
var resources = db.Activities.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projId).ToList();
resources. ????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this via a [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) query to only pull the specific properties that you need (in this case the `ResourceID` property) for each of the elements within your collection :

```
// Get your resources that meet your requirement
var resources = db.Activities.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projId).ToList();
// Get your Resource IDs from your previous query
var resourceIds = resources.Select(r => r.ResourceID);
```

You could actually just perform this in a single call if you preferred :

```
// This will return a list of ResourceIDs that match
var resourceIds = db.Activities.Where(a => a.ProjectID == projId)
                               .Select(a => a.ResourceID)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is the variable ids a list that I can iterate and change the values for each resource in the list?

Comment: The IDs that are returned will be their own separate collection and would have no relationship with the resources that they were pulled from. You could certainly iterate through the IDs, but you would likely need to pull the actual entities themselves if you wanted to make changes to them. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, a little bit hard to understand. The numbers of column ResourceID are the ID of the ID of the Resource table. If I have those ID for each Resource in this list, couldn't I then use that to iterate and add or change data to the tables?

Comment: Right. The result of the `Select()` statement will simply be an array that contains all of your `ResourceID` values that met your original constraint. So you could use these to access certain resources and make changes to them, but making changes to these IDs wouldn't actually have any effect. I just wanted to clarify that this collection of ID values on its own isn't really capable of doing anything besides being iterated through.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are saying. I have to test the code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, just one more question about this. How do I iterare the list? How do I use the line with the resourceIds. ????

Comment: Just use your preferred type of loop (i.e. `foreach(var id in resourceIds){ /* code */ }`).

Comment: A foreach, of course! I didn't thougth about that! Great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is:

```
var resources = db.Activities.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projId).Select(x => x.ResourceID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a list of the Activities.  What you need to do is to select the item you want--in this case the ResourceID column.

```
var resources = db.Activities.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projId)
    .Select(x => x.ResourceID)
    .Distinct() // Thought you might want this
    .ToList();
```

You can also use a different format like this, which can sometimes be clearer.

```
var resources = (from a in db.Activities
                 where a.ProjectID == projId
                 select a.ResourceID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your query if you want to get list of int..

```
    var resources = db.Activities.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projId).Select(x => x.ResourceID).ToList();
```